# Filter an array or list by consecutive pairs based on a matching rule

Tags: algorithm, list, f#, sequence, seq

This is probably trivial, and I do have a solution but I'm not happy with it. Somehow, (much) simpler forms don't seem to work and it gets messy around the corner cases (either first, or last matching pairs in a row).

To keep it simple, let's define the matching rule as *any two or more numbers that have a difference of two*. Example:

`> filterTwins [1; 2; 4; 6; 8; 10; 15; 17]`
`val it : int list = [2; 4; 6; 8; 10; 15; 17]`

The code I currently use is this, which just feels sloppy and overweight:

```
let filterTwins list =
    let func item acc =
        let prevItem, resultList = acc
        match prevItem, resultList with
        | 0, [] 
            -> item, []
        | var, [] when var - 2 = item
            -> item, item::var::resultList
        | var, hd::tl when var - 2 = item && hd <> var
            -> item, item::var::resultList
        | var, _ when var - 2 = item
            -> item, item::resultList
        | _ 
            -> item, resultList

    List.foldBack func list (0, [])
    |> snd
```

I intended my own original exercise to experiment with `List.foldBack`, large lists and parallel programming (which went well) but ended up messing with the "easy" part...

#### Guide through the answers

- [Daniel's last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097167/filter-an-array-or-list-by-consecutive-pairs-based-on-a-matching-rule/5097307#5097307), 113 characters*, easy to follow, slow
- [Kvb's 2nd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097167/filter-an-array-or-list-by-consecutive-pairs-based-on-a-matching-rule/5097511#5097511), 106 characters* (if I include the function), easy, but return value requires work
- [Stephen's 2nd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097167/filter-an-array-or-list-by-consecutive-pairs-based-on-a-matching-rule/5099610#5099610), 397 characters*, long winded and comparably complex, but fastest
- [Abel's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097167/filter-an-array-or-list-by-consecutive-pairs-based-on-a-matching-rule/5260679#5260679), 155 characters*, based on Daniel's, allows duplicates (this wasn't a necessity, btw) and is relatively fast.

There were more answers, but the above were the most distinct, I believe. Hope I didn't hurt anybody's feelings by accepting Daniel's answer as solution: each and every one solution deserves to be the selected answer(!).

** counting done with function names as one character*

Comment: sorry, I noticed it didn't work in some cases. I fixed it and un-deleted.

Comment: small tip: you can do away with the let line before match by `let func item (prevItem, resultList) =`

Comment: @gradbot: thanks, a simple but good tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this do what you want?

```
let filterTwins l = 
    let rec filter l acc flag =
        match l with
        | [] -> List.rev acc
        | a :: b :: rest when b - 2 = a -> 
            filter (b::rest) (if flag then b::acc else b::a::acc) true
        | _ :: t -> filter t acc false
    filter l [] false
```

This is terribly inefficient, but here's another approach using more built-in functions:

```
let filterTwinsSimple l =
    l 
    |> Seq.pairwise 
    |> Seq.filter (fun (a, b) -> b - 2 = a)
    |> Seq.collect (fun (a, b) -> [a; b])
    |> Seq.distinct
    |> Seq.toList
```

Maybe slightly better:

```
let filterTwinsSimple l =
    seq { 
        for (a, b) in Seq.pairwise l do
            if b - 2 = a then 
                yield a
                yield b 
    }
    |> Seq.distinct
    |> Seq.toList
```

Comment: +1 this works, too. Apparently we can't do without flagging (or keepHead in kvb's answer). I liked the simplicity of your earlier answer better, but like you said, it didn't include the rh-sides of the last pairs.

Comment: @Abel - I added code demonstrating an arguably simpler approach. I would never do it this way. Maybe someone more familiar with the standard modules can offer a more efficient method.

Comment: @Daniel - Apparently, you and kvb are on the same page, your second solution looks quite similar to his (hers). Tx once more! PS: is the `Seq.collect` the expensive one here, or `Seq.distinct`?

Comment: @Abel - I added one more solution, I like better.

Comment: @Abel - not 100% sure what would be _most_ expensive, but my guess is `collect`. It's the number of steps involved, more than a particular step, that concerns me.

Comment: @Daniel: yes, I noticed your last solution, thanks. Altogether I have quite something to experiment with! Also notice the solution that kvb chose in his second approach, it would make your middle solution easier.

Comment: @Abel - Which part? We both use the same number of functions (except I'm calling `toList` at the end) and he's using `windowed`/`concat` whereas I'm using `pairwise`/`collect`. They seem more or less the same.

Comment: @Daniel, I meant the `collect` vs `concat`. The second being easier to use because it doesn't require a function. But I agree, both solution are very similar ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
let filterPairs f =
  let rec filter keepHead = function
  | x::(y::_ as xs) when f x y -> x::(filter true xs)
  | x::xs -> 
      let rest = filter false xs
      if keepHead then x::rest else rest
  | _ -> []
  filter false

let test = filterPairs (fun x y -> y - x = 2) [1; 2; 4; 6; 8; 10; 15; 17]
```

Or if all of your list's items are unique, you could do this:

```
let rec filterPairs f s =
  s
  |> Seq.windowed 2
  |> Seq.filter (fun [|a;b|] -> f a b)
  |> Seq.concat
  |> Seq.distinct

let test = filterPairs (fun x y -> y - x = 2) [1; 2; 4; 6; 8; 10; 15; 17]
```

**EDIT**

Or here's another alternative which I find elegant.  First define a function for breaking a list into a list of groups of consecutive items satisfying a predicate:

```
let rec groupConsec f = function
| [] -> []
| x::(y::_ as xs) when f x y -> 
    let (gp::gps) = groupConsec f xs 
    (x::gp)::gps
| x::xs -> [x]::(groupConsec f xs)
```

Then, build your function by collecting all results back together, discarding any singletons:

```
let filterPairs f =
  groupConsec f
  >> List.collect (function | [_] -> [] | l -> l)

let test = filterPairs (fun x y -> y - x = 2) [1; 2; 4; 6; 8; 10; 15; 17]
```

Comment: +1 Appears to work, but still feels awfully contrived. You introduce some concepts I wasn't aware of (`as` keyword, for one), tx for that.

Comment: @Abel - I've added a cleaner option if you know that your list elements are all unique (e.g. in your example, they appear to be monotonically increasing).

Comment: Actually, they are unique (though I had test cases like `[1;4;6;2;3;17]`). Tx for showing this "clean" solution.

Comment: @Abel - I added a third alternative which I like, and which doesn't require unique elements.

Comment: @kvb - should that be `groupConsec` instead of `groupSeq` in `filterPairs`?

Comment: @Daniel - yep, I'll fix it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution is in the spirit of your own, but I use a discriminate union to encapsulate aspects of the algorithm and reign in the madness a bit:

```
type status =
    | Keep of int
    | Skip of int
    | Tail

let filterTwins xl = 
    (Tail, [])
    |> List.foldBack
        (fun cur (prev, acc) ->
            match prev with
            | Skip(prev) when prev - cur = 2 -> (Keep(cur), cur::prev::acc)
            | Keep(prev) when prev - cur = 2 -> (Keep(cur), cur::acc)
            | _ -> (Skip(cur), acc))
        xl
    |> snd
```

Comment: Thanks for showing an alternative with foldBack, the disc. union makes it look a bit simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution which uses a similar discriminate union strategy as my other answer but it works on sequences lazily so you can watch those twin (primes?) roll in as they come:

```
type status =
    | KeepTwo of int * int
    | KeepOne of int
    | SkipOne of int
    | Head

let filterTwins xl = 
    let xl' =
        Seq.scan
            (fun prev cur ->
                match prev with
                | KeepTwo(_,prev) | KeepOne prev when cur - prev = 2 ->
                    KeepOne cur
                | SkipOne prev when cur - prev = 2 ->
                    KeepTwo(prev,cur)
                | _ ->
                    SkipOne cur)
            Head
            xl

    seq { 
        for x in xl' do
            match x with
            | KeepTwo(a,b) -> yield a; yield b
            | KeepOne b -> yield b
            | _ -> ()
    }
```

Comment: +1, interesting, esp because of the laziness. Yes, it was an experiment with twin primes (essentially just to test multi-threading, but then I got carried away).

Answer (score 0):

for completeness sake, I'll answer this with what I eventually came up with, based on the friendly suggestions in this thread.

The benefits of this approach are that it doesn't need `Seq.distinct`, which I believe is an improvement as it allows for duplicates. However, it still needs `List.rev` which doesn't make it the fastest. Nor is it the most succinct code (see comparison of solution in question itself).

```
let filterTwins l = 
    l 
    |> Seq.pairwise 
    |> Seq.fold (fun a (x, y) -> 
        if y - x = 2 then (if List.head a = x then y::a else y::x::a) 
        else a) [0]
    |> List.rev 
    |> List.tail
```